# Why Azure VM gets deallocated by VS DevTest Lab

Tags: visual-studio, azure, virtual-machine

Here is a situation:

An Azure Windows 10 VM is working through a day and is being used via RDP without a problem, while suddenly RDP drops and RDP is no longer a mean to connect. Looking at Azure portal, in an Activity Log, one can see that the VM is deallocated and the Entity that started the action is *VS DevTest Lab*.

[image]

While I've been using some Azure Fluent API for .Net to test start and stop of VM, those tests never came up as being triggered by VS DevTest Lab.

Can someone explain what VS DevTest Lab mean when it comes to practically determining who triggered a VM deallocation? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13):

I believe this is because in DevTest Labs you can have the auto-shutdown configured to save on expenses. Check to see if that is configured in the portal

[image]