# VM classic keeps shutting down and deallocating itself

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created a new classic Azure VM, with Windows server 2016 OS.
It seems to run for about 20 hours or so and shuts down and deallocates itself.

I have searched through the event viewer logs on the VM but can't see anything that would indicate a reason for shut down.

Comment: Did you stop the Auto-shutdown service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [Why Azure VM gets deallocated by VS DevTest Lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638297/why-azure-vm-gets-deallocated-by-vs-devtest-lab)

Scroll down on your VM properties and find Operations.  Right under Operations, check to see if the Autoshutdown service is enabled - and then adjust the settings as desired (e.g. turn off autoshutdown, change the time at which it is scheduled, etc.).

The intent is that on a Visual Studio subscription where you're using this for testing, you can conserve money by starting the VM when you get in the office, and then having it shut down when you reasonably expect nobody to be in the office.

IF it's this cause - what you should see is at https://portal.azure.com, in the VM's log that it is "Azure DevLabs" shutting down your servers.

Comment: Yes, this appears to be on by default. Resolved my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

vm cannot deallocate itself, look at the vm activity log in the azure portal to determine what shut it down.